# How to convert an array into an object using stdClass()

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I have made the following array:

```
$clasa = array(
        'e1' => array('nume' => 'Nitu', 'prenume' => 'Andrei', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e2' => array('nume' => 'Nae', 'prenume' => 'Ionel', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 27),
        'e3' => array('nume' => 'Noman', 'prenume' => 'Alice', 'sex' => 'f', 'varsta' => 22),
        'e4' => array('nume' => 'Geangos', 'prenume' => 'Bogdan', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e5' => array('nume' => 'Vasile', 'prenume' => 'Mihai', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 25)
);
```

I would like to know how to convert this array into an object using stdClass(), I'm a PHP beginner, a simple example would be very helpful, I've tried searching for similar questions, but the answers are complicated and go beyond my understanding of basic classes and objects.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You just add this code

```
$clasa = (object) array(
            'e1' => array('nume' => 'Nitu', 'prenume' => 'Andrei', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
            'e2' => array('nume' => 'Nae', 'prenume' => 'Ionel', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 27),
            'e3' => array('nume' => 'Noman', 'prenume' => 'Alice', 'sex' => 'f', 'varsta' => 22),
            'e4' => array('nume' => 'Geangos', 'prenume' => 'Bogdan', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
            'e5' => array('nume' => 'Vasile', 'prenume' => 'Mihai', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 25)
);
```

If you want to see is this stdClass object just call this

```
print_r($clasa);
```

If you want to convert an array to object code will be

```
$arr = array('a'=>'apple','b'=>'ball');
$arr = (object) $arr;
```

You don't need to use stdClass. It will automatically converted to stdClass

Comment: Not working for nested arrays

Comment: you would have to do the conversion recursively for the nested arrays, see @darleys answer below

Comment: Try this way for nested arrays:

$class = (object) [
        'e1' => (object) ['num' => 'Nitu', 'sex' => 'm'],
        'e2' => (object) ['num' => 'Nae', 'sex' => 'm']
 ]

Answer (score 71):

The quick and dirty way is using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) and [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) which will turn the entire array (including sub elements) into an object.

```
$clasa = json_decode(json_encode($clasa)); //Turn it into an object
```

The same can be used to convert an object into an array. Simply add `, true` to `json_decode` to return an associated array:

```
$clasa = json_decode(json_encode($clasa), true); //Turn it into an array
```

---

An alternate way (without being dirty) is simply a recursive function:

```
function convertToObject($array) {
    $object = new stdClass();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = convertToObject($value);
        }
        $object->$key = $value;
    }
    return $object;
}
```

or in full code:

```
<?php
    function convertToObject($array) {
        $object = new stdClass();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = convertToObject($value);
            }
            $object->$key = $value;
        }
        return $object;
    }

    $clasa = array(
            'e1' => array('nume' => 'Nitu', 'prenume' => 'Andrei', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
            'e2' => array('nume' => 'Nae', 'prenume' => 'Ionel', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 27),
            'e3' => array('nume' => 'Noman', 'prenume' => 'Alice', 'sex' => 'f', 'varsta' => 22),
            'e4' => array('nume' => 'Geangos', 'prenume' => 'Bogdan', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
            'e5' => array('nume' => 'Vasile', 'prenume' => 'Mihai', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 25)
    );

    $obj = convertToObject($clasa);
    print_r($obj);
?>
```

which outputs (note that there's no arrays - only `stdClass`'s):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [e1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nume] => Nitu
            [prenume] => Andrei
            [sex] => m
            [varsta] => 23
        )

    [e2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nume] => Nae
            [prenume] => Ionel
            [sex] => m
            [varsta] => 27
        )

    [e3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nume] => Noman
            [prenume] => Alice
            [sex] => f
            [varsta] => 22
        )

    [e4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nume] => Geangos
            [prenume] => Bogdan
            [sex] => m
            [varsta] => 23
        )

    [e5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nume] => Vasile
            [prenume] => Mihai
            [sex] => m
            [varsta] => 25
        )

)
```

So you'd refer to it by `$obj->e5->nume`.

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/L0PZUkQr)

Comment: It's already an array, so why do you need to convert it into an array *again*?

Comment: Awesome, but from what I've read, this solution is more or less slower to execute.

Comment: @AmalMurali It was to add to the point that this can be used to convert `array -> object` and `object -> array`. Read the post again: *The same can be used to convert an object into an array*.

Comment: @Alexandrw That is true. Alternatively you can check my edit for a non-dirty solution.

Comment: The benefit of this solution `json_decode(json_encode($clasa))` over just using `(object)` to cast the array into an object is that the latter doesn't do it recursively so any inner arrays remain arrays.

Comment: I hate how people just take easier looking option instead of embracing the proper one, this one is almost complete and shows two methods much better than simple typecasting

Comment: Works for nested arrays also

Answer (score 24):

If you want to recursively convert the entire array into an Object type (stdClass) then , below is the best method and it's not time-consuming or memory deficient  especially when you want to do a  recursive (multi-level) conversion compared to writing your own function.

```
$array_object = json_decode(json_encode($array));
```

Comment: It looks like still not all of array are converted

Answer (score 19):

One of the easiest solution is

```
$objectData = (object) $arrayData
```

Comment: Does not work with nested arrays. They will still be arrays, not `stdClass`.

Answer (score 8):

To convert array to object using stdClass just add `(object)` to array u declare.

EX:

```
echo $array['value'];
echo $object->value;
```

to convert object to array

```
$obj = (object)$array;
```

to convert array to object

```
$arr = (array)$object
```

with these methods you can swap between array and object very easily.

---

Another method is to use json

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);
```

But this is a much more memory intensive way to do and is not supported by versions of PHP <= 5.1

Answer (score 4):

Array to **stdClass** can be done in php this way.
(stdClass is already PHP's generic empty class)

```
$a = stdClass:: __set_state(array());
```

Actually calling stdClass::__set_state() in PHP 5 will produce a fatal error. thanks @Ozzy for pointing out

This is an example of how you can use __set_state() with a stdClass object in PHP5

```
class stdClassHelper{

    public static function __set_state(array $array){
        $stdClass = new stdClass();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value){
           $stdClass->$key = $value;
        }
        return $stdClass;
    }
}

$newstd = stdClassHelper::__set_state(array());
```

Or a nicer way.

```
$a = (object) array();
```

Comment: Doesn't work with nested arrays

Answer (score 3):

or you can use this thing

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
$obj = json_decode(json_encode($arr));
print_r($obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this  [Tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)

```
<?php
function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return array
            return $d;
        }
    }

    function arrayToObject($d) {
        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return object
            return $d;
        }
    }

        // Create new stdClass Object
    $init = new stdClass;

    // Add some test data
    $init->foo = "Test data";
    $init->bar = new stdClass;
    $init->bar->baaz = "Testing";
    $init->bar->fooz = new stdClass;
    $init->bar->fooz->baz = "Testing again";
    $init->foox = "Just test";

    // Convert array to object and then object back to array
    $array = objectToArray($init);
    $object = arrayToObject($array);

    // Print objects and array
    print_r($init);
    echo "\n";
    print_r($array);
    echo "\n";
    print_r($object);


//OUTPUT
    stdClass Object
(
    [foo] => Test data
    [bar] => stdClass Object
        (
            [baaz] => Testing
            [fooz] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [baz] => Testing again
                )

        )

    [foox] => Just test
)

Array
(
    [foo] => Test data
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [baaz] => Testing
            [fooz] => Array
                (
                    [baz] => Testing again
                )

        )

    [foox] => Just test
)

stdClass Object
(
    [foo] => Test data
    [bar] => stdClass Object
        (
            [baaz] => Testing
            [fooz] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [baz] => Testing again
                )

        )

    [foox] => Just test
)
```