# Posting JSON To Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am trying to make a post request of json to Laravel. The request is received on the server however when I try to access a property I get: 
**"Trying to get property of non-object"**.
On the client I'm using angularjs.

angular:

```
$http.post($rootScope.globals.basePath+"login/handleAjax",{"id" : obj.values[0].id,"profileUrl" : obj.values[0].publicProfileUrl}).success(function(data){
             console.log("got success!",data);
         });
```

laravel:

```
class LoginController extends BaseController {
/*User logs in to linkedin and sends his id through ajax to this function*/
public function handle_ajax() {
    $data = Input::all();
    *//Clockwork is just a debugging extension I'm using*
    Clockwork::info($data->id); **//"Trying to get property of non-object".**
}
```

Note: I can see in Fiddler that the JSON being sent is valid and that it reaches the controller+method (http 200).

The post request itself (As seen with Fiddler)

```
Headers: 
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
...
Text View:
{"id":"my id","profileUrl":"http://www.linkedin.com/pub/yoel-blum/51/373/76"}
```

Comment: Isn't it `Input::json()->all()` ?

Comment: Laravel does not know you've posted JSON. You'll have to `json_decode` it yourself or use `Input::json()->all()` that is not documented yet, although in the sources (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L429).

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve it : $data = Input::json()->all();
        return $data->id;  and I get the same error ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**NOTE: this answer is only applicable for old Laravel versions (4.2 and earlier)!**

Laravel's `Input::all` method returns an associative array, not an object of PHP's stdClass.

```
$data = Input::all();
$data['id']; // The ID of the request
```

Comment: I am not using `all()` but `json()`, will output the json received

Answer (score 70):

### Update: Laravel 5

Please note as of **Laravel 5.0**, the `Input` facade has been removed from the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests) (and in 5.2 it was also [removed from the list](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/2adbbbd91e9d6e2d569cc56f138b7273efe25651#diff-ea70a5765dbab9fd8032c1d439521db8L178) of default Facades provided) in favor of directly using the `Request` class that `Input` invokes, which is `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

Also, as of the **Laravel 5.1** [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests), all references to the `Request` *facade* have been removed, again in preference of using the `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance directly, which it [encourages you to do](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#accessing-the-request) via dependency injection in either:

...your Controller Method:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = $request->json()->all();
    }
}
```

...or a Route Closure (as of **5.3**):

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
    $data = $request->json()->all();
});
```

### json() and ParameterBag

It's worth noting that `$request->json()` returns an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag`, and that `ParameterBag`'s `->all()` method returns **an associative array**, and not an object as the OP expected.

So one would now fetch the rough equivalent of **`$_POST['id']`** as follows:

```php
$data = $request->json()->all();
$id = $data['id'];
```

### `Input` and `Request` facades: Current Status

Both facades have been removed from the official documentation (as of [5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests)), and yet they [both also remain](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.php) in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Request.php) with no 'deprecated' label.

As mentioned earlier, [`Input` was removed](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/2adbbbd91e9d6e2d569cc56f138b7273efe25651#diff-ea70a5765dbab9fd8032c1d439521db8L178) as a default facade ('alias') in 5.2, but as of 5.4, the `Request` facade [remains a default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.4.9/config/app.php#L219).

This seems to imply that one *could* still use the `Request` facade to invoke methods on the Request *instance* (e.g. `Request::json()`), but that using dependency injection is simply now the officially preferred method.

Comment: Any idea how to retrieve an stdClass object from that `ParameterBag `, not array?

Comment: @DrakeES You'll need to just cast it as an object: `(object) Request::json()->all()` since `ParameterBag`'s params are stored internally as an associative array, and at present there is no "return as object" option. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272011/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-using-stdclass

Comment: @Greendrake See [this thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/443) for an interesting historical discussion on exactly this, including a comment from T.O. himself (which looks familiar, haha).

Comment: @jdunk can I send few parameters in the post and few in the json?

Answer (score 8):

To expand (and correct) the above, in Laravel 5 you would retrieve JSON as shown:

```
public function handle_ajax(Request $request) {
    $data = (object) $request->json()->all();
    Clockwork::info($data->id);
}
```

In non-trivial examples you might want to also validate your input first.

Comment: Thanks for [indirectly] bringing this to my attention @Pete. My answer at the time was correct for Laravel 5.0, but it was indeed later (when 5.1+ came out) then somewhat inaccurate to have said just "in Laravel 5, what you want is Request::json->all()" -- even though that actually still totally works -- because it was removed from the documentation (although not the source code) in favor of what you noted here. I updated my answer accordingly.