# How to get curl POST data?

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

I'm trying to POST data using command line using curl.

```
curl -v POST -d ' { "data1": "sample1", "data2": "sample2" } ' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: BASIC vkslnkg561mZEqCq3l3RglAOAZ7d8XBeg2VjIAyC" http://localhost/Bowling/public/api/foo
```

I'm using Laravel 5, is there any way to get the Authorization token and the data passed in routes/controller?

Right now Im using

```
getallheaders();
```

I'm able to get Authorization token but not the data { "data1": "sample1", "data2": "sample2" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this: file_get_contents("php://input")

```
Route::any('api/foo', function(){   
    $allHeaders = getallheaders();  

    return (file_get_contents("php://input"));
    /* Rest of the code */
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5 JSON data can be fetched with

$request->json()->all()

See this answer [Posting JSON To Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219482/posting-json-to-laravel)

Comment: Hey @thomas.g, its giving me a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you can have a look at the log file to see what's happening server side.