# Error using POST with JSON string and CORS

Tags: php, json, xml, laravel-5, cors

I'm trying to send a JSON string to my localhost server using `XMLHttpRequest`. Everything works fine with `GET` and I can view my response but when I use `POST` I get the following error message in console..

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost/t`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://test.com` is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

**Request website**

```
var obj = { "table":"customers", "limit":11 };
var dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);

var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
};

var url = 'http://localhost:80/t';
var method = 'POST';
var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log("Success");
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  console.log("Error");
};

xhr.send(dbParam);
```

On my localhost server I have the following..

**Route**

```
Route::post('/t', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'JsonController@getJson'));
```

**Controller**

```
    public function getJson(Request $request) {
    // First we fetch the Request instance
    $request = Request::instance();

    // Now we can get the content from it
    $content = $request->getContent();

    return $content;
    }
```

**Cors.php**

```
'supportsCredentials' => true,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'application/json'],
'allowedMethods' => ['POST'],
'exposedHeaders' => ['*'],
'maxAge' => 0,
```

Comment: Your JS code is sending a JSON request body so there will be no `$_POST['dbParam']`. I'm sure a quick Google search will reveal how to read raw request body data in Laravel. You should also set a request header of `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33298205/283366

Comment: Thanks @Phil! I've made the changes you suggested but now I get a 500 error. ` (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/t. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://test.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

Comment: What on Earth are you doing in your controller? Why `$request = Request::instance()`? You already have the `$request`. It should just be `$content = $request->json()->all();`. Also, if you get an error response (405, 500, etc), the first thing you should do is check your server's error log

Comment: SOLVED. It was a problem with the CSRF token.