# Receive an array of objects in php controller

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I want to send an array of objects to a php controller, and im doing like this:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "payment/pagamento",
        data: $.param(vm.listProdsCar),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);   

        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

My array `vm.listProdsCar`:
[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5uCq.png)

and in the php controller im reeiving like this but is not working:

```
foreach($request->all as $req){

 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$req->name.'");</script>'; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be wiser to send the data as JSON instead of urlencoded. Also the [`.success` and `,error` methods are deprecated and removed from AngularJS 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: Read [Posting JSON To Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33298205/5535245).

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't going to construct an STD Class from your javascript input, it's going to convert them to associative arrays, so you should access them as an associative array:

```
$req['name'];
```

Come to think of it, you also don't need to define the `Content-Type` header as what you've got is already the default.

Comment: i´ve tried that but it shows me the console.log(response) of the .error(function(response) wich means it fail..

Comment: @YukariTakeba That's because you need to call `all()` as a function.

Comment: doesnt work either... i tried to pass just one position of the array like this vm.listProdsCar[0] it works, but if i pass all array it stop working