# Sending JSON to Laravel using POST request

Tags: php, laravel

so I am trying to get a hang of laravel HTTP requests and am facing an error when sending a post request that contains a JSON body...

When I first tried it out, I got an error using the same code that worked for a post request that had params attached to the URL...

My store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'details' => 'required|string',
            'completed' => 'required',
            'modified' => 'required'
        ]);
        $user = Auth::id();
        $userDetails = UserDetailModel::find(1)->UserDetailId;
        $todo = new UserTodoModel;
        $todo->UserDetailId = $userDetails;
        $todo->Title = $request->title;
        $todo->Details = $request->details;
        $todo->completed = $request->completed;
        $todo->modified = $request->modified;
        $todo->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully added!'
        ], 200);
    }
```

Error I got

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `UserTodo` (`UserDetailId`, `Title`, `Details`, `completed`, `modified`, `DateModified`, `DateCreated`) values (1, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-05-19 01:06:50, 2020-05-19 01:06:50)) in file D:\My Workspace\Laravel\awiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 671
```

I then found this post 
[Posting JSON To Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219482/posting-json-to-laravel/33298205#33298205)

Which in turn led me to use this

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request);
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'Title' => 'required|string',
            'Details' => 'required|string',
            'completed' => 'required',
            'modified' => 'required'
        ]);
        $user = Auth::id();
        $userDetails = UserDetailModel::find(1)->UserDetailId;
        $testData = (object) $request->json()->all();
        // dd($testData);
        $todo = new UserTodoModel;
        $todo->UserDetailId = $userDetails;
        $todo->Title = $testData->Title;
        $todo->Details = $testData->Details;
        $todo->completed = $testData->completed;
        $todo->modified = $testData->modified;
        dd($testData);
        $todo->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully added!'
        ], 200);
    }
```

Then I started getting this error and am not sure why...

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: stdClass::$Title in file D:\My Workspace\Laravel\awiz\app\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserTodoController.php on line 49
```

EDIT

Sorry, I forgot to post the dd() output...

When I use dd($testData) I get this.

```
{#1251
  +"0": array:8 [
    "UserTodoId" => 0
    "UserDetailId" => 1
    "Title" => "Test item2"
    "Details" => "This is a test item2"
    "completed" => 1
    "modified" => 0
    "DateCreated" => "2020-05-20T00:00:00.000000Z"
    "DateModified" => "2020-05-22T00:00:00.000000Z"
  ]
}
```

but when I use dd($testData->Title) I end up getting the same error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$Title
```

I am running laravel 7.0

As for my request, I am using postman.

This is the JSON am sending

```
[
    {
        "UserTodoId": 0,
        "UserDetailId": 1,
        "Title": "Test item2",
        "Details": "This is a test item2",
        "completed": 1,
        "modified": 0,
        "DateCreated": "2020-05-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "DateModified": "2020-05-22T00:00:00.000000Z"
    }
]
```

and those are my headers
[image: and those are my headers]

EDIT 2

What would I do if I'm sending a nested JSON, how would I go about trying to access the inner JSON? 
Nested JSON

```
{
    "fName": "Ahmed",
    "lName": "Abdelsalam",
    "email": "test@tessssssdst.com",
    "password": "123456789",
    "userDetails": {
        "FirstName": "Ahmed",
        "MiddleName": "Adil",
        "LastName": "Abdelsalam",
        "Designation": "Cashier",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "DOB": "2020-05-20T00:00:00.000000Z"
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        // Creating the user entry
        // JSON conversion
        $userData = (object) $request->json()->all();

        // Validation
        // $userData->validate([
        //     'fName' => 'required|string',
        //     'lName' => 'required|string',
        //     'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
        //     'password' => 'required|string'
        // ]);
        // Creating instance
        $user = new User;
        $user->first_name = $userData->fName;
        $user->last_name = $userData->lName;
        $user->email = $userData->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($userData->password);
        // Saving instance
        $user->save();

        // Creating the user details entry
        // Getting user ID
        $userId = User::where('email', $userData->email);
        // JSON conversion
        $userDetailsRawData = $userData->userDetails;
        $userDetailsData = (object) $userDetailsRawData->json()->all();
        dd($userDetailsData);
        // Validation
        // $userDetailsData->validate([
        //     'FirstName' => 'required|string',
        //     'MiddleName' => 'required|string',
        //     'LastName' => 'required|string',
        //     'Designation' => 'required|string',
        //     'Gender' => 'required|string',
        //     'DOB' => 'required',
        //     'Email' => 'required|string|email|unique:userdetails',
        // ]);
        // Creating instance
        $userDetails = new UserDetailModel();
        $userDetails->FirstName = $userDetailsData->FirstName;
        $userDetails->MiddleName = $userDetailsData->MiddleName;
        $userDetails->LastName = $userDetailsData->LastName;
        $userDetails->Designation = $userDetailsData->Designation;
        $userDetails->Email = $userData->email;
        $userDetails->Gender = $userDetailsData->Gender;
        $userDetails->DOB = $userDetailsData->DOB;
        $userDetails->UserId = $userId;
        // Saving instance
        $userDetails->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
        ], 201);
    }
```

Without adding the `json()->all()` I end up getting an array and when I add it I get an error, I tried converting the array using json_decode() but I couldn't use '->' to access elements in the resulting JSON I seem to be missing something here

Comment: You should post the output of your dd() and the way that you are doing the request.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Are you sure you set the `Content-Type: application/json` with your request?

Comment: Not sure about what you want to access in the second edit but is a hard requirement using objects to access the elements of your requests? If yes you still can set as `true` the second parameter in the `json_decode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `Title` of your request is empty or is not present in the request

This can be due to a typo, error in the caps or something similar.

The first error shows an error in thee database trying to insert a record with an explicit required filed with null.

The second tells you are trying to access to a property that has not being initialized.

**Edit:**

After reviewed the dump of your variable and your request it's visible that you are setting your requests as an element of one array.

That is why the member `Title` doesn't exists.
If you try to access like this:
`$testData[0]->Title` you will find your value.

You don't get errors before because you are assigning the values to the main `$testData` object.

My suggestion is update your request like this:

```
{
    "UserTodoId": 0,
    "UserDetailId": 1,
    "Title": "Test item2",
    "Details": "This is a test item2",
    "completed": 1,
    "modified": 0,
    "DateCreated": "2020-05-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
    "DateModified": "2020-05-22T00:00:00.000000Z"
}
```

Sending just one object instead of an array with one element.

Comment: I did check and recheck a bunch of times for typos, I even changed all the variable names and still to no vail.

Comment: I just added a bit to my question if you don't mind check that bit too