# How to get values from complex object in php

Tags: php, object

I am working with the Google Calendar API, trying to get the ids from the response object.

Here is the object.

```
Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList Object
(
[collection_key:protected] => items
[internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[etag] => "1454629096373000"
[itemsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry
[itemsDataType:protected] => array
[kind] => calendar#calendarList
[nextPageToken] => 
[nextSyncToken] => CIj2xtSj38oCEj1nY2FsL....
[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
        [items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [kind] => calendar#calendarListEntry
                        [etag] => "145461934381000"
                        [id] => tbcv49j3eg@group.calendar.google.com
                        [summary] => Appointments
                        [timeZone] => America/Chicago
                        [colorId] => 24
                        [backgroundColor] => #a47ae2
                        [foregroundColor] => #000000
                        [selected] => 1
                        [accessRole] => reader
                        [defaultReminders] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [kind] => calendar#calendarListEntry
                        [etag] => "14546290978873000"
                        [id] => o6lkfgdovcv2r8@group.calendar.google.com
                        [summary] => Test Calendar
                        [timeZone] => America/Chicago
                        [colorId] => 14
                        [backgroundColor] => #9fe1e7
                        [foregroundColor] => #000000
                        [selected] => 1
                        [accessRole] => reader
                        [defaultReminders] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

So I did this to get them into an array.

```
foreach ($calendarList['items'] as $key => $value) {
     $ids[] = $calendarList['items'][$key]['id'];
}
```

But I would like to reference them in a more Object oriented style like

```
$calendarList->items->
```

Can I do this somehow?

Comment: Yes you can but suggested reading..http://michaelkimsal.com/blog/php-is-not-object-oriented/

Comment: @ern  Thanks for the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$calendarListNew=new stdClass();
$calendarListNew->items=new stdClass();

$i=1;
foreach ($calendarList['items'] as $key => $value) {
     $calendarListNew->items->$i = $calendarList['items'][$key]['id'];
     $i++;
}
```

So you can fetch the values like :

```
$calendarListNew->items->{'1'}
```

Comment: This is more like it.  But I am getting an error.   `syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: Try this $calendarListNew->items->{'1'}

Comment: @skribe: If that helped, accept my answer bro. Thanks. Good day.

Answer (score 0):

`$value` will have the each items, u can use the following

```
foreach ($calendarList['items'] as $key => $value) {
    $value = (object) $value;
    $ids[] = $value->id;
}
```

[How to convert an array into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272047/5798881)

Comment: which u want to be object

Comment: That is an improvement since it is more concise.  But not really what I am looking for.   I can get an id if I use `$calendarList['items'][0]['id']` but I am looking for an object oriented way to the "id