# Converting json_decode to an object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, stdclass

I get the following output with json_decode

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [...] => ...
            [...] => ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [...] => ...
            [...] => ...
        )
```

What I want to do is import this to a class so I can call and reference the data from memory.

From research I found this:
[How to convert an array into an object using stdClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272011/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-using-stdclass)

However, I am not sure if stdClass is the way I want to go?

Comment: How does your JSON string look like?

Comment: [{"first_name":"Jason","last_name":"Pass", [...]

Comment: Can't you just do json_decode($array), (with no second option) or am I missing something?

Comment: why aren't you sure about stdClass?

Comment: If you want it to go into a user-defined class, you can write a constructor for your class that takes the array as an argument and copies the values into appropriate properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function definition from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

Considering your JSON string `[{"first_name":"Jason","last_name":"Pass", [...]`, you must be using `json_decode` with its second parameter set to TRUE.

That means that objects from the JSON string are returned as associative arrays. If you omit the second parameter (or use the default FALSE value), you will get:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'first_name' => string 'Jason' (length=5)
      public 'last_name' => string 'Pass' (length=4)
      ...
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      ...
```

This means objects from the JSON string are preserved as objects.

However, the array containing your objects will remain an array, because this is how it should be and you should not force it to be an object. There is no good reason to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Put object just before starting of the array

```
$arr = Array([0] => Array
    (
        [...] => ...
        [...] => ...
    )[1] => Array
    (
        [...] => ...
        [...] => ...
    ));

 $arr = (object) $arr;
```