# a better way to convert an array to an object

Tags: php

Having the following array,

```
$dataset = [
    ['item1' => 'value1'],
    ['item2' => 'value2'],
    ['item3' => 'value3'],
];
```

I need to convert it to this `stdClass` object

```
$dataset = [
    'item1' => 'value1',
    'item2' => 'value2',
    'item3' => 'value3',
];
```

In order to do that, I use these nested `foreach`

```
$object = new stdClass;

foreach ($dataset as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $object->{$key} = $value;
    }
}

// At this point $object is the expected output
```

I look for a better way to do it, one in which I can avoid foreach nesting

The final expected output is

```
stdClass Object
(
    [item1] => value1
    [item2] => value2
    [item3] => value3
)
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `$arr = ['a' => 10]; (object) $arr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will be an elegant way to do the job

```
$dataset = (object)call_user_func_array('array_merge', $dataset);

print_r($dataset);
```

Answer (score 3):

check this! it's working fine

first `array_merge` and then `json_encode` and `json_decode` for `stdClass`

```
<?php
$dataset = [
    ['item1' => 'value1'],
    ['item2' => 'value2'],
    ['item3' => 'value3'],
];


$dataset = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $dataset);
$dataset= json_decode(json_encode($dataset));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dataset);
```

and also you can used `object` for stdClass like

```
$dataset=(object) $dataset;//make sure first you merge array
```

there is a multiple way to get `stdClass object`. So, [here is the most valuable answer for stdClass object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272011/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-using-stdclass)

Comment: very nice... I started down the json_decode/encode nesting path, but didn't merge the array first

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I missed where you wanted to flatten the array.  I will add Bilal Ahmed suggestion for merging the arrays.

For your case example you do not need to use the `json_decode(json_encode($dataset));`

However, keep in mind that `json_decode(json_encode($dataset));` is the better solution if you have nested arrays.

```
$dataset = [
    ['item1' => 'value1'],
    ['item2' => 'value2'],
    ['item3' => 'value3'],
];

$dataset = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $dataset);    
$object = (object)$dataset;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($object);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [item1] => value1
    [item2] => value2
    [item3] => value3
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I do not get the expected output

Comment: Are you expecting a json output.

Comment: Doesn't yield the expected answer