# I want to convert Array to stdobject

Tags: php

i have this code

```
$array = (car => 'yes', 'bike' => 'no', 'cycle' => 'yes');

print_r($array);
```

My output is

```
Array
(
    [car] => yes
    [bike] => no
    [cycle] => yes
)
```

I want output like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [car] => yes
    [bike] => no
    [cycle] => yes
)
```

i am using php version 5.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Comment: Is there any way you could upgrade your PHP (although it doesn't affect this question).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272011/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-using-stdclass

Comment: ArrayObject https://3v4l.org/3qLWn is a nice way if you want both

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this

```
$array  = array('car' => 'yes', 'bike' => 'no', 'cycle' => 'yes');
$array=json_decode(json_encode($array), false);
print_r($array);
```

your output is like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [car] => yes
    [bike] => no
    [cycle] => yes
)
```

Comment: `$array  = (object) array(...)` would suffice